# Add access date ahead of URL

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

1. I want to add access date ahead of the url. How to modify the bibtex file?
2. Could you tell me how to add `[Online]` as well?

> Hawking, S. 2000. Professor Stephen Hawking's website. [Online]. [Accessed 25 August 2017]. Available from: http://www.hawking.org.uk/

The full `.bst` is available [here](https://pastebin.com/hKpegiD2) which is made by `makebst`.

A MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\reff.bib}
@misc{hawking2000,
 author = {Hawking, S.},
 year = {2000},
 title = {{Professor Stephen Hawking's website}},
 urldate = {2017-08-25},
 url = {http://www.hawking.org.uk/}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib,url}
\begin{document}

As argued by \cite{hawking2000}, \dots

\bibliographystyle{myHarvard}
\bibliography{\reff}
\end{document}
```

The function of url format is

```
FUNCTION {format.url}
{
  url
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    {
       "\urlprefix\url{" swap$ * "}"  *  }
  if$
}
```

Comment: That bit of the `.bst` file only prints the URL. I guess it would be easier to help if we could see the entire `.bst` file *and* a short example document with an example citation that we can use to test our modifications (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). If the `.bst` file is on CTAN or can be downloaded elsewhere, a link is enough, but if it is already a custom style it would probably be best if you could upload it to a text-sharing website (please avoid file-sharing websites where one has to download `.zip`s or the like).

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for the advice. The question is modified as required.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following function solve the issue for me.

```
FUNCTION {format.urldate}
{ urldate duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "~[Accessed: " swap$ * "]" * "[Online]" add.period$ swap$ * }
  if$
}
```